# how to export a html page content to MS word {javascript, ajax, jquery code}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ms-word

how to export  a html page content to ms word {javascript, ajax, jquery code}

Comment: It might help if you explained better. Posting the question multiple times won't change the fact people don't understand what you are trying to accomplish..

Comment: http://www.coolutils.com/Online-HTML-Converter.php ---<sample site
how can I do with javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with simply saving it as a .doc instead of .html

I understand this might be a bit limited. But you might need to provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little Adobe air application that needed to create word documents to be printed by merging a template with some data. Instead of figuring out the Word API, I just use HTML templating and saved the resulting HTML locally as a .doc (as Russel Dias points out) and Word opens it without a problem. Client is still happily using it.